# readonly property is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I use this code in this code I multiply first two column(i.e. answer1 and answer2 ) input value into third column(i.e. answer3 ) input.

I set the third column input read Only by jQuery  but when I click on third column input and press any key as enter,shift,0 to 9 etc. then the value of third column(i.e. answer3 ) input increase but I don't do this.the value should not increase.

```
<html>

<body>
    <table class="chetan">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>answer1</th>
                <th>answer2</th>
                <th>answer3</th>
            </tr>
            <thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>first</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>second</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>third</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("table.chetan >tbody >tr >td:nth-child(4)").addClass("ccg").children("input").attr('readonly', true);
            $("table.chetan >tbody >tr >td:nth-child(4) >input").keydown(function () {
                return false;
            });
            var mult = 0;
            $("input:text").val(0);
            $("input:text").keyup(function () {
                var p1 = $(this).val();
                var p2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:not(.ccg) input").not(this).val();
                mult = parseFloat(p1) * parseFloat(p2);
                $(this).parent().parent().find("td.ccg input").val(mult);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` like `.prop('readonly', true)`

Answer (score 2):

Its not working because your selector query returns an array. Solve it by iterating and setting property for each

```
 $("table.chetan >tbody >tr >td:nth-child(4)").addClass("ccg").children("input").each(function () {
     $(this).attr('readonly', true);
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9t3q/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not attr you use with readonly. You need to use prop.

Comment: My dears all I used prop also but same problem and I can not use prop("disabled",true) because this value can not access at this situation please give me specific solution...

Answer (score 0):

use `disabled` instead of `readonly` that will work too

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..This is working.

$("table.chetan >tbody >tr >td:nth-child(4)").addClass("ccg").children("input").each(function () {
     $(this).attr('disabled','disable');
 });

attr('readonly', true) will not work.

Above given code working.check it.
```

[click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0lV0wkMdi6qbyc8LrYK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$("input:text").keyup(function () {` and due to that reason keyup on every input="text" is calculating the result. Please note that events can work as usual for readonly property too.

And you have used `var p1 = $(this).val();` what indicates first parameter for multiplication is always your focused input="text". Right?

And second parameter `var p2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:not(.ccg) input").not(this).val();` indicates first input="text" only.

So If you press(basically keyup) any key on third input="text"(result text with readonly property), on that case value for pressed key can't take as field is readonly but calculation can process for (existing value of third input="text") and (first input="text").

**Solution:**
Please change `$("input:text").keyup(function () {` with `$("input:text:not([readonly])").keyup(function () {` so that calculation not will work when you will keyup on readonly input="text" and code will work as you have expected.

**Suggestion:**
Please change `var p2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:not(.ccg) input").not(this).val();` to any other simplified code as this is unnecessary complicated one. :)

Comment: Thanks my bro your description is right and it helped me in my program thanks again...In all help your help is best and differ from other...